# Can't print out keys of Stocktwits dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am learning to fetch data from Stocktwit's API and am currently exploring the API's data. I executed the following code to extract information about the last 30 tweets about Apple's stock:

```
import requests

a=requests.get('https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json')
a=a.json()
print(a.keys())
>> dict_keys(['cursor', 'messages', 'response', 'symbol'])
```

I can see there are four keys in Apple's stock dictionary. However I don't see the sentiment's key, which is basically what I am looking for: How many times does the keyword "bullish" appear? and How many times does the word "bearish" appear?

If I manually enter the [link](https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json) directly from my browser I can manually see how many times "bearish " and "bullish" keywords appear on Apple's stock. How can I do this with Python 3.5?

EDIT: I even tried looking for my keywords in one of the dictionary's keys as suggested by [this](https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json)
post.

```
for bearish in a.keys():
print ("the key name is" + bearish + "and its value is" + a[bearish])
>> TypeError: Can't convert 'dict' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sentiment` is buried in the `messages`:

```
from collections import Counter
sentiment_dict = Counter()
for message in a['messages']:
    if 'entities' in message:
        if 'sentiment' in message['entities']:
            sentiment = message['entities']['sentiment']
            if sentiment is not None:
                sentiment = sentiment['basic']
                sentiment_dict[sentiment] += 1
for key, value in sentiment_dict.items():
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
```

**Output**

```
Bearish: 4
Bullish: 8
```

I used `Counter`, which is a specialization of `dict`, to count the frequency of the sentiments.

**Note**

For other folks who are trying to find fields in the JSON, I recommend

```
import json
print json.dumps(a, indent=4)
```

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind suggesting what Python function or method can I use to count the number of times that "Bearish" and "Bullish" appear?

Comment: I modified the example to use the `Counter` class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `a[bearish]` is probably another dictionary. `print()` automatically inserts spaces, so why don't you change your print statement to

```
print ("the key name is", bearish, "and its value is", a[bearish])
```

Which will make it easier to debug what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) instead of `+` to solve your issue.

Look at the following to understand what `format()` does:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': {'aa': 10}, 'b': {'bb': 20}}
>>>
>>> for key in my_dict.keys():
...     print "key :" + key + " and value: " + my_dict[key]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects
>>>
>>> for key in my_dict.keys():
...     print "key : {} and value: {}".format(key, my_dict[key])
...
key : a and value: {'aa': 10}
key : b and value: {'bb': 20}
```